# How to add different images for different cell to a tableView programmatically (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to add different images to different cell in a tableView where i have already a list of string, this is my code, the struct of category:

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name:String
    var image:UIImage
    var isSelected = false
    init(name:String, image:UIImage) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}

extension QCategoryy: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {


    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.name = value
    }
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
}
```

here is where i create the list (which i will then add to the tableView)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire

class NearbyPlaces {
    static func getCategories() -> [QCategoryy] {
        let list:[QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy(name: "Art_gallery", image: UIImage(named: "art_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Bar", image: UIImage(named: "bar_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name :"Night_club", image: UIImage(named: "nightclub_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Movie_theater", image: UIImage(named: "cinema_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Restaurant", image: UIImage(named: "restaurant_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Gym", image: UIImage(named: "gym_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Spa", image: UIImage(named: "spa_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Museum", image: UIImage(named: "museum_button.png")!)]
        return list
    }
```

and finally i add this to the tableView

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CATEGORY_CELL"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
       /* cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none  */
        cell.accessoryType = list[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        cell.imageView?.image = list[indexPath.row].image
        return cell
    }
```

my problem is that after i decided to add the images, so in the struct i added the image  `var image:UIImage` i get in the extension of `QCategoryy`
at the lines `self.init(name: value)` the error: Argument labels '(name:)' do not match any available overloads. How can i do to solve this problem? My goal is just to be able to add the images to the different cells of the tableView (associated with the right name obviously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is probably because your var `isSelected` is being initialized but the other variables aren't. So you might want to initialize everyone at their declaration, like this:

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name = ""
    var image = UIImage()
    var isSelected = false
}
```

or like this:

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name:String
    var image:UIImage
    var isSelected: Bool
    init(name:String, image:UIImage, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

As you're not initialising neither `name` nor `image` when you declare those variables, you have to initialise them somehow.

In your `init` function in your struct you're expecting `name` and `image` as parameters, so you have to add them in you `init` call inside the `extension` and you also need to initialise your `image` variable

```
extension QCategoryy: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {


    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.name = value
        self.image = UIImage()
    }
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value, image: UIImage())
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value, image: UIImage())
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand why do you need that extension , can you please explain why it exists?

Comment: I ran the code snippet in the Playground without the `extension` and it worked as expected. Check my edited answer

Comment: yes but i need the extension to work with swiftyJSON and other frameworks that i need to research the places based on specific categories, so i can't remove it, before i added the images the code work perfectly is after that i get this error

Comment: Ok, I added the `extension` and I think I fixed your problem, check my edited answer